# CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I am getting this error whenever I try to run GCC outside of its installation directory (`E:\MinGW\bin`).

So, let's say I am in `E:\code` and have a file called `one.c`. Running:
`gcc one.c -o one.exe` will give me this error:

```
gcc: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

The only workaround is to navigate to its installation directory, run gcc from there, and specify all the other paths. My environmental variable `Path` contains `E:\MinGW\bin`.

Any suggestions to fixing this problem? I am running Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Did you add it to the path AFTER you got this error using the windows environment variables GUI? If you did, and you're trying to run gcc in the same command shell you were using originally, it isn't going to work. That shell has its own copy of PATH that didn't get changed when you used the GUI. You can see this by typing 


    echo %PATH%

in your command shell. The fastest way to fix it would be to log out and log back in.

Comment: Ah, I figured that just spawning a new instance of CMD.exe would be enough for it to use the new "PATH" variable. However, it works fine now that I've tried logging out and in, it seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: It can be fixed if you change your temp dir environmental variable to a directory that doesn't have spaces in it's name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its specifically told that you need to reboot after you set the environmental variables in windows for migwin.

Comment: incorrect: in Windows 7 (perhaps also Vista) it is sufficient to open a fresh command prompt. In Windows XP it was sufficient to log out and in. No rebooting necessary.

Comment: You don't need to do that. You do however have to load up a new command shell to read the new environment variables you changed.

Answer (score 38):

According to [Code::Blocks wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_MinGW_with_Vista#Executeables), you need to add `C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\MinGW-Version` to your `PATH`. There is no need to restart, but you need to open another terminal in order to get the newest `PATH` settings.

For MinGW-w64, that's `<mingw install directory>\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.0\`

Comment: Nope...  didn't help me one bit.

Comment: It was my problem as well. I'm on 64bit gcc (mingw64 project). Adding <mingw install directory>\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.0\ fixed it.

Comment: In my command-line-only [case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38745252/603516) the problem was fixed by conversely cleaning the `PATH`. ProcMon was very helful in diagnostics.

Answer (score 37):

I had a similar problem, caused by not installing the C++ compiler. In my case I was compiling .cpp files for a Python extension, but the compiler is first invoked as c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe.

Internally, gcc.exe would notice it was asked to compile a .cpp file. It would try to call g++.exe and fail with the same error message:

> gcc.exe: CreateProcess: no such file or directory

Comment: Luis Bruno's answer fixed my problem. Make sure you installed the proper compiler. I'm trying to compile .cpp files with gcc.exe, while g++ is actually required. mingw-get install g++ cleared the error out.

Answer (score 10):

I just had this problem.

In my case, the problem was due to problems when downloading the packages for GCC. The mingw-get program thought it finished the download, but it didn't.

I wanted to upgrade GCC, so I used mingw-get to get the newer version. For some reason, mingw-get thought the download for a particular file was finished, but it wasn't. When it went to extract the file, I guess it issued an error (which I didn't even bother to look -- I just ran "mingw-get update && mingw-get install mingw32-gcc" and left it there).

To solve, I removed gcc by doing "mingw-get remove mingw32-gcc" and also removed the package file (the one mingw-get didn't fully download), which was in the mingw cache folder ("C:\MinGW\var\cache\mingw-get\packages" in my system), then ran the install command again. It download and installed the missing parts of GCC (it had not fully downloaded the package gcc-core).

That solved my problem.

Interestingly enough, mingw-get was smart enough to continue the download of gcc-core even after me having deleted the package file in the cache folder, and also removed the package mingw32-gcc.

I think the more fundamental problem was that since gcc-core files were not installed, cc1 wasn't there. And gcc uses cc1. I guess that, when gcc tried to start cc1, it used CreateProcess somewhere passing the path of cc1, which was not the path of an existing file. Thus the error message.

Comment: My disk was full during install and I guess this caused the problem for me, even if mingw did still install without a warning.

Answer (score 10):

So this is a stupid error message because it doesn't tell you *what* file it can't find.

Run the command again with the verbose flag `gcc -v` to see what gcc is up to.

In my case, it happened it was trying to call `cc1plus`. I checked, I don't have that. Installed mingw's C++ compiler and then I did.

Comment: I had a similar issue (internally it was attempting to call cc1).  cc1 was included with my distribution, but the include path was not in my PATH.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem.

After a recheck of my `PATH`, I realized I installed both `Mingw` (64 bit) and `Cygwin` (32 bit). 
The problem is that both `Mingw` and `Cygwin` have `g++`.

By deactivating the path of `Cygwin`, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

In the "give a man a fish, feed him for a day; teach a man to fish, get rid of him for the whole weekend" vein,

```
g++ --help
```

shows compiler options.  The g++ -v option helps:

```
  -v                       Display the programs invoked by the compiler
```

Look through the output for bogus paths.  In my case the original command:

```
g++ -v "d:/UW_Work/EasyUnit/examples/1-BasicUnitTesting/main.cpp"
```

generated output including this little gem:

```
-iprefix c:\olimexods\yagarto\arm-none-eabi\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.5.1/
```

which would explain the "no such file or directory" message.

The "../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.5.1/" segment is coming from built-in specs:

```
g++ -dumpspecs
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but none of currently listed solutions helped at first try.

`-v` option didn't give any additional clues.

Had to resort to [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to be able to find the root of the problem.

Dumping `g++` process file activity revealed numerous attempts to find `cc1plus` executable at different paths. There were paths to old GCC version among them.

But that old version resided in separate folder and was not at all referenced from the new version I tried to run.

At last the obsolete path was found in system %PATH% environment variable.
After removing it, the new version started to work without errors.

Comment: After hunting down this issue for years, I had a similar issue relating to cc1/cc1plus.  GCC for some reason was looking for cc1.exe along all paths in the PATH.  After failing to find anywhere, gcc errored with `CreateProcess: No such file or directory.`  Added a suitable cc1.exe path to PATH and build was successful.

Comment: Good idea to use ProcMon, since the error is not so verbose, and apparently there are many possible causes for this specific (cryptical) error message. In my case, I found out that g++ was looking for `as` (the assembler), which was missing. Installing it finally solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Was getting the same error message when trying to run from Cygwin with links to the mingw install.

Using the same install of mingw32-make-3.80.0-3.exe from http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ and the mingw shell option from Start -> Programs -> on a WinXP SP3 and gcc is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and none of the suggested fixes worked for me.  So even though this is an old thread, I figure I might as well post my solution in case someone else finds this thread through Google(like I did).

For me, I had to uninstall MinGW/delete the MinGW folder, and re-install.  After re-installing it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem. Initially, adding the GCC bin folder to my system path did not resolve the problem. I found two solutions.

The first was to run a batch file I found in the root of the MinGW install, mingwbuilds.bat. It (apparently) launches a command prompt configured correctly to run GCC. The second was to remove double-quotation marks from the GCC install bin folder that I had added to my user path variable. I tried this after noticing the batch file not using double-quotes around the install bin path.

Extra Details

I found the batch file accidentally while browsing the install folder tree trying to locate the various executables that weren't launching (according to the -v output). I found some information on the MinGW wiki, http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started, in the Cautions and Environment Settings sections, that indicates why the MinGW installer does not set up the system or user path to include the install folder. These seem to confirm the batch file is intended to launch a command prompt suitable for running GCC from a Windows prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a couple of release distro for MinGW. Which one did you try? For the record, I ran into the exact same problem as the OP and the distro I got was from TDM-GCC 4.5.1.

I found the MinGW distro [here](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?call=fortran) seems to work far better and sets things up correctly. So for anyone running into this retarded 'createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory' error and can't get things to work, uninstall your existing MinGW and try the one I linked instead.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might arise if you have different versions of programs.

For instance, you have 1-year old `gcc` and you want to compile a C++ source code. If you use `mingw-get` to install `g++`, `gcc` and `g++` will suddenly have different versions and you ware likely to find yourself in this situation.

Running `mingw-get update` and `mingw-get upgrade` has solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because you use *uppercase suffix stuff.C* rather than lowercase stuff.c when you compile it with Mingw GCC. For example, when you do like this:

```
gcc -o stuff stuff.C
```

then you will get the message: `gcc: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`

But if you do this:

```
 gcc -o stuff stuff.c
```

then it works. I just don't know why.

Comment: Because many Unix compilers follow the convention that `.c` is the extension for C language files, and `.C` is (along with `.c++`, `.cpp`, and `.cxx`) the extension for C++ files, and mingw follows this convention since its roots are Unix.

Comment: You could also define the parameter `-x c` to specify explicitly `c` as the language for the following input files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very long path, and there's a file in there somewhere (not gcc.exe) but another file, that gcc.exe is accessing from the path..

So when I cleared the path, it worked

```
C:\MinGW>cd bin


C:\MinGW\bin>where gcc.exe
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
C:\Perl64\site\bin\gcc.exe
```

^^ So running gcc from there will definitely run the ming gcc.exe

```
C:\MinGW\bin>type file6.c
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int num1,num2;
scanf("%2d %4d",&num1,&num2);
printf("a=%d b=%d",num1,num2);
scanf("%d",&num1);
//flushall();
printf("c=%d",num1);
}
```

Compiling it I got this error

```
C:\MinGW\bin>gcc file6.c
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

My PATH was huge

```
C:\MinGW\bin>path
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\P......
```

C:\MinGW\bin>path | grep -io "ming"

It didn't have ming there.

C:\MinGW\bin>echo MING | grep -io "ming"
MING

(and yeah that grep works..the path didn't have ming there)

Clearing my path completely, led it to work!

```
C:\MinGW\bin>set PATH=

C:\MinGW\bin>gcc file6.c

C:\MinGW\bin>
```

So, it's not clear yet precisely what it was in the PATH that led to the clash. What directory, what file.

**Update-**

The above seems to be correct to me but to add, it's also not a simple case of something earlier in the path clashing.. because normally the current directory takes precedence. And it does here in so far as gcc --version shows it's running the ming one and not one of the ones in a conflicting directory. So there's something funny going on that, if the conflicting directory is in the path) ,  one has to either do .\gcc or add `.` to the start of the path or add `c:\MinGW\bin`  before any conflicting directories in the path. this is the case even when you're in `C:\MinGW\bin`  and that's strange. And when it gives an error, it is still running Ming's gcc but (For some reason) looking at the conflicting directory too, as I see from process monitor.   There may be more of an answer here http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_MinGW_with_Vista   in the link mentioned in the very upvoted answer here

That's Ming32 bit..

Looking at Ming 64bit, probably has te same issue, but I see, interestingly, it comes with a bat file that (sensibly) actually puts the bin directory at the tart of the path.  And it looks like that is a standard way of running Ming gcc properly.

The code::blocks IDE (sensibly) also puts the bin directory at the start of the path.  If you run a C program that shows environment variables then you see that.

Answer (score 0):

Add `E:\MinGW\bin` to the `PATH` variable.

Comment: If he didn't added it do PATH, the prompt won't even recognize gcc as a program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I'm running cygwin)

Starting a shell through cygwin.bat didn't help, but starting a shell through MingWShell did. Not quite sure why, but I think it had something to do with the extra layer that cygwin puts between the executing script and the underlying filesystem.

I was running pip install from within a virtual env's cygwin to install django sentry..

Comment: how do you load mingwshell?

Comment: That's a good question. This was from a while ago and since then I've reformatted, but from memory I installed via http://www.mingw.org/wiki/getting_started

Comment: can you show me a specific pic e.g. on google images that shows what the mingw gui you have in mind/remember is?

Answer (score 0):

(Referring to original problem) 
Today's version of `mingw` (see post date) 
All I had to do was to set the path in same shell I ran `gcc`.
Took me an hour to remember how to set `DOS variables`...

```
A:> set PATH=C:\MinGW\bin\;
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32\;C:\WINDOWS\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\
A:> gcc hi.c
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried everything with no result,, What fixed the problem for me was changing the order of the library paths in the PATH variable. I had cygwin as well as some other compilers so there was probably some sort of collision between them. What I did was putting the C:\MinGW\bin; path first before all other paths and it fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

try to put the path in the system variables instead of putting in user variables in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error message, because I was using MinGW-w64, and the commands in `<install path>\bin` all had a weird prefix. I attempted to call executables in the "target alias" directories instead of in `<install path>\bin` directories, which resulted in even more problems. That's a no-no according to the [FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Usable%20compiler%20executable/). The solution for me, then, was to create symbolic links to all the prefixed commands. I opened an elevated command prompt and used something like `mklink gcc.exe                                x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` for every executable, and now my build works.

Answer (score 0):

Although post is old I had the same problem with mingw32 vers 4.8.1 on 2015/02/13. Compiling using Eclipse CDT failed with this message. Trying from command line with -v option also failed. I was also missing the cc1plus executable.

The cause:
I downloaded the command line and graphical installer from the mingw32 site. I used this to do my initial install of mingw32. Using the GUI I selected the base tools, selecting both the c and c++ compilers.

This installer did an incomplete install of the 32 bit c++ compiler. I had the g++ and cpp files but not the cc1plus executable. Trying to do an 'update' failed because the installer assumed I had everything installed.

To fix I found these sites: 
http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
I downloaded and ran this 'online install'. Sure enough this one contained the missing files. I modified my PATH variable and pointed to the 'bin' folder containing the g++ executable. Rebooted. Installed 64 bit Eclipse. Opened Eclipse and the 'Hello World' c++ program compiled, executed, and debugged properly.

Note: the 64bit installer seems to default to UNIX settings. Why can't an installer determine the OS??? Make sure to change them.

I spent an entire evening dealing with this. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org i suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I already had a g++ compiler installed thru MinGW (the package **mingw32-gcc-g++**) but I needed a C compiler so I ran mingw-get-setup.exe where I was able to have it install the **mingw32-base** package, the one with the C compiler.

Alas! I had this error when I use gcc to compile:

*gcc: error: createprocess: no such file or directory*

What I did was, still using the MinGW Installation Manager, I removed the C and C++ compiler packages, namely **mingw32-base**  and **mingw32-gcc-g++** and ALSO deleted the C:\MinGW directory itself. Then I reran mingw-get-setup.exe, installed **mingw32-base**, and voila, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this error started occurring when the length of the command line exceeded cygwin's limit. Which was 32000 bytes.

You can check the limit using this command:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
32000
```

The solution in the project I am working has not been finalized yet, but possible solutions include:

- using binaries built from link libraries instead built from all the project files.
- shortening the names of directories that contain many source code files, as the names of the directories are repeated multiple times.
- reviewing the list of files used by the linker.

Likely there are many more possible solutions too, the simplest perhaps is finding a way to increase the length limit.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me is simply:

1. When you save the program, let's say its named *hi.cpp* put it into folder e.g. *xxl* then save your program.
2. Cut this folder and put it into the bin folder of the mingw.
3. When you call the program:

   ```
   ------ g++ xxl\hi.cpp --------
   ```