# gcc/g++ gives me error "CreateProcess: No such file or directory"

Tags: gcc, g++

-edit- it seems to be a problem with path and not being able to find its bin/ folder. Even though the g++ is in that bin directory.

I am trying to launch g++ on windows in my app but i get the error below. How do i fix it? side note i can do `g++ dummy.cpp` in the prompt with no problem.

args `-o file.exe -x c++ -`

stdout

```
: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

-edit- my code is...

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

string gcc_bin="E:/dev/external/MinGW/bin/g++.exe";
string gcc_folder="E:/dev/external/MinGW/bin/";

int launch_gcc(ostringstream&o);
int main(){
    ostringstream osz;
    osz << "#include <cstdio>" << endl << "int main(){ printf(\"hello\"); } return 4; }";
    {
        launch_gcc(osz);
    }
    return 0;
}





void ErrorExit(PTSTR);
int launch_gcc(ostringstream&o)
{

    char buf2[4096];
char buf[4096];
ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PATH%", buf, 4095);
OutputDebugString(buf);

    sprintf(buf2, "PATH=%s;%s;\0\0", gcc_folder.c_str(), buf);

    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

    HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr = NULL;

    HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;  
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

    if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
    ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe")); 
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
    ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation"));

    if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd, &g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
    ErrorExit(TEXT("StderrRd CreatePipe")); 
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
    ErrorExit(TEXT("Stderr SetHandleInformation"));

    if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) 
    ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe")); 
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
    ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation")); 

    ZeroMemory( &startupInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA); 
    startupInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    startupInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr;
    startupInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    ZeroMemory( &processInformation, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

    bool bSuccess = CreateProcess(
        gcc_bin.c_str(),
        " -o \"c:/dev/src/git/myprj/theout.exe\" -x c++ -",
0,
  0,
  1,
  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
  0,//buf2,
  0,//gcc_folder.c_str(),
  &startupInfo,
  &processInformation
);
   if ( ! bSuccess ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
   else 
   {
      // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
      // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
      // of the child process, for example. 

      CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);
   }


    { 
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    auto sz=o.str();
    bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, sz.c_str(), sz.size(), &dwWritten, NULL);
    //if ( ! bSuccess ) break; 

    if ( ! CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr) ) 
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle")); 
    } 



    #define BUFSIZE 1024*4
    { 
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    chBuf[0]=0;
    if (!CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr)) 
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdOutWr CloseHandle")); 

    for (;;) 
    { 
        bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

        bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
                            dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        chBuf[dwWritten]=0;
        if (! bSuccess ){ 
            printf("%s", chBuf);
            break; 
        }
    } 
    }

    { 
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdErr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

    if (!CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr)) 
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdOutWr CloseHandle")); 

    for (;;) 
    { 
        bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

        bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdErr, chBuf, 
                            dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        chBuf[dwWritten]=0;
        if (! bSuccess ){ 
            printf("%s", chBuf);
            break; 
        }
    }
    auto a=1;
    }


    return 0;
}

void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Comment: it might help to post the code that you use to call gcc from within your application. I suspect you will need to specify the full path to the gcc executable, as there is most likely no "search path" like in the command interpreter.

Comment: Does the error come from your call? As far as I understand how gcc/g++ work, they start other process and it may be that they can't find those. Is your command prompt where g++ works the regular Windows command prompt or Cygwin's?

Comment: @lothar: Done. @Alexey: In cmd, g++ works. With my C++ code (now pasted). I run it and get the error. The error is from g++ stdout.

Comment: According to your code, the error comes not from gcc but from your code: _Your program_ can't start gcc. Have you tried using backslashes in paths, as in here: `string gcc_bin="E:\\dev\\external\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe";`?

Comment: @Alexey: Yes, also it IS coming from gcc. Otherwise my function would return errors rather then finding it in stdout. For example edit the folder and i'll get a window msg rather then output from stdout

Answer (score 6):

Try to add the path to g++ compiler into `PATH` environment variable:

```
TCHAR *path;
TCHAR *newpath;
DWORD dwSize = GetEnvironmentVariable(TEXT("PATH"), NULL, 0);

path = new TCHAR[dwSize];
GetEnvironmentVariable(TEXT("PATH"), path, dwSize);


dwSize += MAX_PATH;
newpath = new TCHAR[dwSize];
_tcscpy_s(newpath, dwSize, TEXT("E:\\dev\\external\\MinGW\\bin;"));
_tcscat_s(newpath, dwSize, path);
SetEnvironmentVariable(TEXT("PATH"), newpath);

delete[] path;
delete[] newpath;
```

At this point environment block of your process contains `PATH` variable that includes the path to g++ compiler. Note: this does not affect user's environment.

You can use `char` instead of `TCHAR`, and `strcpy`, `strcat`. This way will work in both cases: with Unicode enabled and without Unicode support.

Answer (score 4):

It is very likely that double instances of the compiler exist on the system.

If so, try the following for experiment so that the one under current path could run for the source compile:

```
D:\cmn_dev\mingw64\bin>.\g++ HelloGcc.cpp -o Hello.exe
```

Hope this could be of help. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Which GCC for windows are you using?  MinGW, Cygwin, something else?

Have you tried logging in and out again as indicated in this question? [CreateProcess: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/mingw-gcc-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory)

On Windows, GCC needs its bin directory to be on the PATH, it won't look in the directory of its own binary.  Try putting something like

```
wchar_t buf[4096];
ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%PATH%", buf, 4095);
OutputDebugStringW(buf);
```

into your program before the call to g++ to make sure the directory is on the path for your program's environment (if you're not running your program in a debugger, use wprintf instead)

Watch out if you tried to install GCC on a path with a space character in it, both MinGW and Cygwin warn against this.

Comment: I tried but maybe i did it wrong. I added my code above. Adding in `path=gcc_bin;path;\0\0` cause error `87 parameter is incorrect` when i tried executing my createproccess.

Comment: does "E:/dev/external/MinGW/bin" show up in buf?  If not, you need to add it to your system's environment (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519 on XP, windowskey->"environment" on Vista/7) and log in and out again.

Comment: Other ppl will have to use this app and i dont want to mess around with their environment vars. Besides, i add it into ExpandEnvironmentStrings as my code shows. Its just i do it wrong or something bc i get the parameter error when i call my own createproccess

Comment: I forgot to mention. I did restart with it in my path and no luck. BUT i am NOTusing ExpandEnvironmentStrings with create process as it gives me the 87 parameter is incorrect error

Comment: I had the same problem, and this question give a good direction: on cmd.exe: `> which g++.exe` outputs `...\avr8-gnu-toolchain\avr\bin\g++.exe` which certainly doesn't compile a console application. Prepending %path% with MinGW/bin directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue and got it resolved after adding the "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin" to the PATH system variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sysinternals ProcessMonitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to trace the system calls that are issued by your code (CreateFile, CreateProcess, Registry queries) along with their success and return value. This also shows all different attempts to find the executable which is not found by your code - most times this makes it obvious, which mistake (e.g. typo, escaping, white-space in path etc.) caused the code not to find the g++ executable.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sysinternals ProcessMonitor like BertNase said. What you do is find the .exe name that is doing the compiling under the Process Name column, like gcc.exe. Then look in the Result column and anything that is not a SUCCESS check it out. I think what you are looking for is a NAME NOT FOUND result though.

I had this same problem and did what I just mentioned above, I found that gcc.exe was getting a NAME NOT FOUND result for cc1obj.exe. So I made an educated guess and went into my MinGW folder under \libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.5.0 (the version number might not be the same for you) and made a copy of cc1.exe then renamed it as cc1obj.exe. And wala, that fixed the problem.

You probably aren't missing the same file but it sounds like following this process will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got a problem yesterday with a program not being able to handle a path like this:

```
<some stuff>;%ProgramFiles%\path\to\bins;<some other stuff>
```

I replaced it with :

```
<some stuff>;C:\Program Files\path\to\bins;<some other stuff>
```

and it worked. You might want to check this out

Answer (score 0):

The error you get say that the function of gcc "CreateProcess" try to access some file and can't find it.

Obviously if gcc catch the error, it's running, so nothing wrong with your PATH.

However gcc can't find a program or a library needed for the compilation. It's a strange error that I know on mingw32. My best advice will be to re-installed mingw32. You may have change some file use by the program.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the problem while setting up Atom. But later I found out that my MinGW was copied from Codeblocks folder. Reinstalling the packages through official MinGW installer and adding the directory path (for my case C:\MinGW\bin) in

> Advance System Settings>Environment Variables > Path

solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but who knows it can help.

For me, I replaced the complete path with the location of the compiler.

So:

```
set path="< folder that contains the compiler>"
```

I think that maybe the current path has some elements in it that are not parsed properly by the compiler (no double quotes, no spaces, etc)