# Eclipse c++ build error: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I installed MinGW and CDT following some tutorials. I'm trying to compile and run "hello world" code. There are no errors in eclipse but when I compile the code I get this error:

```
22:48:32 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test3 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.8.1\\include\\c++" "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.8.1\\include\\c++\\mingw32" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\test3.o" "..\\src\\test3.cpp" 
g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

22:48:32 Build Finished (took 135ms)
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I saw this answer before i posted and it didn't solve my problem

Comment: If you can't explain why your case is different, your question will still be closed as duplicate. You can't just open the same question again, just because the existing question doesn't have "enough" answers.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a silly question to ask, but did you save the file somewhere before building it? I've had an error like this that was solved by saving it on my Desktop or wherever.

Edit: There seems to be several people with problems using MinGW. You mentioned you looked at previous stackoverflow questions, do they include these:

[Eclipse CDT error: Unable to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847442/eclipse-cdt-error-unable-to-compile)
[MinGW error: No such file or directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330383/mingw-error-no-such-file-or-directory-exists)

Other solutions suggest you should try compiling the program via command line, which...shouldn't be a problem since it's just "Hello, World".

Comment: it is saved in the project folder