# trying to install mercurial via easy_install

Tags: python, review-board

I am using Active Python 2.5.1, Mercurial 1.8.1 and TortoiseHg 1.1.0
on Windows XP (all x86)
I am trying to configure a mercurial repo in reviewboard. For that it
requires mercurial python module
So when i try to install mercurial via easy_install i get the
following error

```
C:\>easy_install mercurial==1.8.1
Searching for mercurial==1.8.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/mercurial/
Reading http://mercurial.selenic.com/
Reading http://www.selenic.com/mercurial
Reading http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/
Best match: mercurial 1.8.1
Downloading http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-1.8.1.tar.gz
Processing mercurial-1.8.1.tar.gz
Running mercurial-1.8.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:
\docume~1\username\locals~1\temp\easy_install-7l0ykf
\mercurial-1.8.1\egg-dist-tmp-egcnt6

cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit
status 1
```

I have installed gcc through MinGW

---

Thanks shu zOMG chen, 1.8.1 is a requirement so can't really change that.The second link did help, but now there's another problem. After removing -mno-cygwin occurences from distutils\cygwinccompiler.py I ran easy_install mercurial==1.8.1. The trace is as folows :

```
C:\>easy_install mercurial==1.8.1
Searching for mercurial==1.8.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/mercurial/
Reading http://mercurial.selenic.com/
Reading http://www.selenic.com/mercurial
Reading http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/
Best match: mercurial 1.8.1
Downloading http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-1.8.1.tar.gz
Processing mercurial-1.8.1.tar.gz
Running mercurial-1.8.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\docume~1\username\locals~1\temp\easy_install-05el_6\mercurial-1.8.1\egg-dist-tmp-zsfye0

gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

C:\>
```

Please Help
Regards

Comment: I just googled for the term `gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory` and I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/gcc-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

From your output it appears that easy_install is trying to build mercurial with an option that requires some cygwin parts.  If you're using mingw gcc you might want to look at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BuildingOnWindows for instuctions on how to build in windows.

Is there a reason you're using 1.8.1?  The latest version is 2.1.2.

Googling around, [Compiling with cython and mingw produces gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o) might help you with this too.

Answer (score 0):

There are also exe and msi installers for Windows at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads.

In my opinion, the TortoiseXXX changes the mental picture of what is behind the wrapper.  It was difficult for me to explain to my colleague how to work with CVS correctly when TortoiseCVS was used.

Off topic: For your own other purpose, try also Git instead (http://git-scm.com/)  The idea is very similar.  I guess the Git is going to win statistically.

The msysgit (Windows) is nice, the functionality is comparable with the original Linux one, the included Git Gui and gitk may have rather strange look (Tcl/Tk), but they are very good for the basic Git operations.