# windows nasm gcc gives error "Createprocess: no such file or directory."

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, mingw, nasm

Unfortunately, I have been forced to switch to windows for now to program assembly code, instead of using Linux. But when trying to link my .obj file produced by NASM, it gives the error `gcc: Createprocess: No such file or directory."

My code:

```
GLOBAL _main
EXTERN _printf

_main:
    push message 
    call _printf
    add esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db 'Hello, world',10,0
```

I have tried moving my .obj file to the same directory as GCC. I have also tried compiling the entire thing in the same directory as GCC. I am not using any environment variables when compiling with my batch file, instead changing directory by hand. I also have GCC installed in the same directory as G++ and all the other compilers that come with MinGW.

Why does it give this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what command(s) are you using to build this? Giving us the error message is only half the problem.

Comment: Don't let 'em force ya, Riley! Stand firm! But if you must, see if this is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/gcc-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Btw, MinGW appears to put some stuff of its own into `main()`, specifically `call    ___main`. I recommend not to implement `main()` in assembly as that call or whatever, when missing, may break things.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's worked for me:

ASM file:

```
; file: blahasm.asm
; assemble with nasm (v 2.10, Mar 12 2012): nasm -f elf32 blahasm.asm -o blahasm.o
bits 32

global _blah

_blah:
  mov eax, 42
  ret
```

C file:

```
// file: blahc.c
// compile with MinGW x86 (gcc v 4.6.2): gcc -Wall -O2 blahc.c blahasm.o -o blah.exe
#include <stdio.h>

extern int blah(void);

int main(void)
{
  printf("blah():%d\n", blah());
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
blah():42
```

I'm surprised that the only format that's worked is `elf32` and that it's supported in a Windows port of gcc, which MinGW is.

**UPDATE**:

I've created an assembly-only program with NASM and MinGW.

ASM file:

```
; file: nsm.asm
; assemble with NASM (v 2.10, Mar 12 2012): nasm -f elf32 nsm.asm -o nsm.o
; compile (link) with MinGW x86 (gcc v 4.6.2): gcc -Wall -O2 nsm.o -o nsm.exe
bits 32

extern ___main
extern _printf

global _main

    section .rdata

textstr:
    db "Hello World!", 10, 0

    section .text.startup

_main:
    call    ___main
    push    textstr
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

I'm running gcc from the "MinGW Shell" (MSYS) and I don't need to specify any additional command line parameters to make the program successfully link with the standard library. And I did not need to do anything special about MinGW and MSYS installation, I think I used all default setup parameters.

Comment: I'm not trying to run this program from a C program as a function. I want to run it in the console. So how can I link to the C library? It doesn't seem to be there in the MinGW folder.