# Is there anything wrong with my command, gcc or something else?

Tags: gcc

During the compiling of a C file in gcc, i typed

> gcc -c kernal.c -o kernal.o

But the outcome stated

> gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is gcc in your environment variable 'path'?

Comment: What operating system are you using, and what command shell? (BTW, you or somebody else misspelled "kernel".)

Comment: I am using windows 7 and using MinGW shell. (i misspelled it on purpose caused i had 2 files of that name)

Comment: Have you looked at here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/gcc-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

SET Path to ur GCC in environmental variables