# How to make 'make' work with mingw32 on Windows 7

Tags: c, makefile, mingw32

I'm pretty new to C and to programming so I hope you guys have a little patience. 
However I try to describe my problem as precise as possible.
I'm using mingw32 on my Windows 7 computer and I just learned about 'make'.
I have written some source-code files and a Makefile. What I want is, that the Makefile
compiles my source-code int object code and then link it together to one executable
(I guess that's nothing wild for a pro).

So here is my code:

first.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"second.h"
int main()
{
float x = 12.0;
printf("Result is: %.2f\n",go_to_the_other(x));
return 0;
}
```

second.h

```
float go_to_the_other(float f);
```

second.c

```
float go_to_the_other(float f)
{
float calc = f + 10;
return calc;
}
```

And the Makefile is (and yes, I used only tabs):

```
second.o: second.c second.h
        gcc   -c   second.c
first.o:    first.c
        gcc   -c   first.c
first:   first.o  second.o
        gcc first.o second.o  -o first
```

This is just an easy example, but it pretty much describes my problem.
I have all files in the same directory, and I use the command line:

```
mingw32-make first
```

But instead of compiling my files, I only get the message:

```
cc  first.c -o first
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc first.c -o first, ...) failed
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'first' failed
mingw32-make: ***[first] Error 2
```

I guess it's probably something really stupid, but I just can't figure out
what I'm doing wrong. I really appreciate any help on this.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Possibly related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321980/yet-another-mingw-gcc-error-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: This is odd. It's executing commands to build `first` that aren't even in your makefile. It seems to be choosing defaults for the make rules for a `c` file. Are the `makefile` you show and the sources all in the same folder, and no other makefile present? Is the file called `makefile` or `Makefile`? Also, I assume you entered `mingw32-make` and not `mingw32 -make`.

Answer (score 1):

So I went and tried it and... it works for me with MinGW-4.7.1 on a Win7 machine....  I'm wondering if make it picking up an environment variable or some such.

Try verifiying the version of make and gcc are what you expect

mingw32-make -v
gcc -v
mingw32-gcc -v

Also Try this makefile and see what happens.

```
CC = mingw32-gcc

second.o: second.c second.h
    $(CC)   -c   second.c
first.o:    first.c
    $(CC)   -c   first.c
first:   first.o  second.o
    $(CC) first.o second.o  -o first
```

Note convert spaces to tabs!

And compile via

mingw32-make SHELL=cmd.exe first

See what happens.