# gcc: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc

I have tried to use other solutions posted on the web for the same error but it doesn't work for me.

I am testing the installation of MinGW compiler on my pc and I get the following error when running the code:

```
gcc -v hello.c

C:\Python34\swigibpy-master>gcc -v hello.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.5.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --
enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-we
rror --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/ hello.c -quiet -dumpbas
e hello.c -mtune=i386 -march=i386 -auxbase hello -version -o C:\Users\E039256\AppData\Local\Temp\cc87BHBZ.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.5.2 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"#include "..." search starts here:#include <...> search starts here: C:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.5.2 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 48c0bd49e9a9404f24c600b71b435d06
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 as -o C:\Users\E039256\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwHyCqZ.o C:\Users\E039256\AppData\Local\Temp\cc87BHBZ.s
gcc: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you checked: [CreateProcess: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6085411/1771479)?

Comment: No doesn't help a bit.

Comment: perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321980/yet-another-mingw-gcc-error-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory it definitely smells like the PATH isn't set up right.  Maybe reinstall mingw gcc...

Answer (score 0):

The `mingw32-gcc`, `mingw32-g++`, etc. binaries exist as an aid to cross development. They are created in a typical build of gcc. They are therefore distributed as the maintainers of GCC meant them to be. The `gcc.exe` indicates that the binary produces binaries for a target equal to the build, while the `mingw32-gcc` binary produces binaries to be executed on the mingw32 target.

You can see that at http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ

Comment: I do not see how this is relevant to the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: My English is not very good, maybe the problem we encountered is different.
  When I encountered a similar problem last time, I first went to the official website to read the document, and then solved the problem according to the content inside.
Another time, I encountered this problem, I re-installed and solved the problem.