# Compiling C++ file at command line on Windows using MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, compilation, mingw

I wrote the following on a notepad and save it as hello_world.cpp in the following folder: C:\cplusplus

```
#include <iostream>

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I brought up cmd.exe and executed the following code to compile the cpp file.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin>g++.exe C:/cplusplus/hello_world.cpp
-o hello_world.o
```

However, I got the following error message:

```
g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

I wonder if someone could point out what I did wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yet Another MinGW "gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13321980/608639) and [mingw32-g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34319405/608639)

Comment: But I have to ask.... Why suffer Linux on Windows problems with Cygwin, MinGW, MSYS and friends? Use [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40504552/608639) for native Windows compilation from the command line. Or setup a Linux VM on Windows and use GCC inside Linux. (When in Rome, do as the Romans do...)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is "/" which is used in Linux. In Windows is "\".
Try:
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin>g++ c:\cplusplus\hello_world.cpp
-o hello_world.o

Answer (score -1):

The instructions do say to re-login after setting MingGW up. I'd reboot, just for good measure.

Comment: i'm new to c++. I started a new post because I was wondering if the code within hello_world.cpp could potentially
be source of the problem. MinGW g++ wasn't recently installed. It came with CodeBlock that I've been using
to learn C++ for a while. I tried the same compilation code on another computer - it seems to execute without any
error message but I couldn't find where hello_world.o file is,

Comment: hello_world.o is wherever you ran the command from. Also, the only place I know of where this happens is when the variables haven't updated the way they should've, so that's why you login. I guess CodeBlocks does something weird with the compiler, I've never tried their bundled compiler.