# 2 novice Questions about GCC in Cygwin

Tags: android, c++, gcc

1) Why could I be getting 'No such file or Directory' on a file that clearly exists, in the same directory, which I'm including with -I?

Example: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VITNw.jpg

2) I've solved this problem before, at least twice. The solution in the past has basically been 'jiggle it until it works', if that makes any sense. Once I solve this problem, I'm immediately going to get smacked in the face with

CreateProcess: No such file or directory

an error which is completely meaningless to me. I've come across numerous theories about what that error might mean, the most concrete of which is that Cygwin wasn't allocated enough memory to do what it needs to do. I've adjusted my environment variables to up its memory limits to a gig, and I still get this problem. It makes debugging error-prone, to say the least.

I've looked through this : [CreateProcess: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/gcc-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory)

but its packed with contradictory solutions that I do not understand. Is it just that this is a very ambiguous error, and I'm going to have to just jiggle more stuff until it works? Is there actually a way around this?

Comment: Care to show us line 19?

Comment: Any particular reason you have a `cstddef` in that directory and don't use the standard header `cstddef`?

Comment: Rawkode, it's line 1 that's breaking, and it's just #include <cstddef>

@Dan, ideally, I'd just link against the android NDK's header for cstddef. I've copied it into this directory to reduce the possibility for error and figure out exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I'd think having a `cstddef` in your working directory would rather increase the possibility for error. What does `locate cstddef` find?

Comment: I won't be home to check until later tonight, but I don't see what difference it would make. The Android NDK isn't installed anywhere significant. I just downloaded it to a folder and need to compile against it. I'm not sure I see why Cygwin ought to have or need default C++ headers. If it does, I'd want to specify the search path with -I as I've done here, anyway, since I'm trying to use the android specific implementation.