# can't install this file (mercury6_2.for) with gfortran

Tags: gfortran

I tried this:

```
 Alan@Alan ~/mercury  
 $ gfortran -o mercury6_2.for
 gfortran.exe: fatal error: no input files; unwilling to write output files
 compilation terminated
```

and:

```
Alan@Alan ~/mercury
$ gfortran -o mercury mercury6_2.for
gfortran.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

My file exist:

```
 Alan@Alan ~/mercury
 $ ls
 big.in      element.in    mercury.inc   mercury6_2.for  README.txt
 close.in    element6.for  mercury6.man  message.in      small.in
 close6.for  files.in      mercury6.tar  param.in        swift.incenter code here
```

gfortran seems to be running in Cygwin:

```
Alan@Alan ~/mercury
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.0 20130302 (experimental) [trunk revision 196403]
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

GNU Fortran comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Fortran
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING
```

So I don't know.

Is there away that I could do this differently?

Comment: Are you sure, that this Mercury is the programming language? As I remember it do not require fortran at any stage of compilation.

Comment: Could you give a link to the README.txt in that folder? Probably that describes the way to build it. Your first try did not work, as the fortran command's -o switch just specify the output name.

Comment: Probably [this question][1]'s answers can help you go further.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory