# LPCXpresso error CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, cmd, microcontroller, toolchain

I know there are multiple questions regarding this subject, but they did not help.
When trying to compile, whatever, I keep getting the same error:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

I guess it means that it can not find the compiler.
I have tried tweaking the path settings

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\nxp\LPCXpresso_7.6.2
326\lpcxpresso\tools\bin;
```

Seems to be right?

I have tried using Sysinternals process monitor
I can see that a lot of ***arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe*** are getting a result of *name not found* but there are a lot of successful results too.

I have also tried reinstalling the compiler and the LPCXpresso, no luck.

If i type `arm-none-eabi-gcc -v` i get the version, so it means its working
but when i am trying to compile in CMD like this `arm-none-eabi-gcc led.c`
i get the same error as stated above

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

Tried playing around more with PATH in enviroments, no luck. I feel like something is stopping LPCXpresso from finding the compiler
The only Antivirus this computer has is Avira and i disabled it. I also allowed compiler and LPCXpresso through the firewall
I have tried some more things, i will add it shortly after trying to duplicate the test.

Comment: Sounds like a typical "Eclipse gone haywire" problem... Once Eclipse has gone haywire, you can spend days trying to fix it. I'd create a new project from scratch and toss all code into the new project.

Comment: @Lundin Tried doing that. I am trying to compile a example program at the moment. It is my first time using this damn program. I mean, i have just a empty main and i am still getting it. It has to be the compiler, but i don't have any ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: From what I remember, you shouldn't need to set the path manually or do any such tweaking. I have two instances of LPCxpresso on my computer and neither is mentioned in my PATH system variable. What is the code you are trying to compile? One of the NXP examples or something else?

Comment: It could be a conflict with some other GCC compiler on your computer. Also, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory).

Comment: The only other compiler i have is SDCC and i removed that from PATH. Its not the LPCxpresso that is in the path, but the compiler folder.

Comment: @Lundin It doesn't even care about the code at the moment. Can leave it empty and same error.

Comment: The `CreateProcess` error is not from LPCXpresso trying to execute the compiler, it's from the compiler trying to execute another program. The exact program `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` is trying to open is `..\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\4.8.4\cc1.exe` ('4.8.4' can probably vary). Can you find this file ?

Comment: @ElderBug Yea, i know it is the compiler. 
I checked the folder. cc1.exe is there. But i remember when i used process monitor it said that cc1 is not found. cc1.exe was found but just cc1(no extension) was not found.

Comment: `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` also need two other executables : `..\arm-none-eabi\bin\as.exe` and `..\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\4.8.4\collect2.exe`. Maybe its one of them ? Also, does the version folder match the version given by `arm-none-eabi-gcc -v` ?

Comment: Files are there and version matches(4.9.3) I have tried reinstalling the compiler. Maybe it has something to do with the fact i am using Windows Vista?

Comment: Try to start gcc as admin (properties->compatibilities, check "run as admin").

Comment: It seems i can not do that. I can run things as admin, but i can not set that option.

Comment: Then can you start a command line as admin, or create a .bat with your command inside and run it as admin ?

Comment: Did it, same 
***arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory***

Comment: Does the same thing happen with an empty .c file as argument ? Also, did you try to reboot ?

Comment: Yea, It does not care about the contents of the file at all at the moment. I am losing my mind over this. It is my second day with this and i am wasting precious time

Comment: @Elderbug maybe a log from Process monitor would shed you some light?

Comment: Maybe a dump from `arm-none-eabi-gcc -v led.c 2>dump.txt`. But actually I'm pretty sure the problem comes from vista and the fact that `cc1` is used without the `.exe`. I'm trying to figure out why, I will come back when I have more info. Also, were you ever able to run an eabi gcc ?

Comment: Well since it is my first time. I can run a command like --version and get a result. But whenever i try to compile (arm-none-eabi-gcc led.c(for example) i get the same message i posted.
dump file : http://justpaste.it/jh6l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is a happy mess with Vista and GCC. Long story short, a CRT function, `access`, has a different behavior on Windows and Linux. This difference is actually mentioned on Microsoft documentation, but the GCC folks didn't notice. This leads to a bug on Vista because this version of Windows is more strict on this point.

This bug is mentioned here : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33281

I have no proof that your problem comes from here, but the chances are good.

The solutions :

1. Do not use Vista
2. Recompile `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` with the flag `-D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS`
3. Patch `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe`

The 3rd is the easiest, but it's a bit tricky. The goal is to hijack the `access` function and add an instruction to prevent undesired behavior. To patch your gcc, you have two solutions : you upload your .exe and I patch it for you, or I give you the instructions to patch it yourself. (I can also patch it for you, then give the instructions if it works). The patching isn't really hard and doesn't require advanced knowledge, but you must be rigorous.

<s>As I said, I don't have this problem myself, so I don't know if my solution really works.</s> The patch seems to be working for this problem.

**EDIT2:**

The exact problem is that the linux `access` have a parameter flag to check whether a file is executable. The Windows `access` cannot check for this. The behavior of most Windows versions is just to ignore this flag, and check if the file exists instead, which will usually give the same behavior. The problem is that Vista doesn't ignore this, and whenever the `access` is used to check for executability, it will return an error. This lead to GCC programs to think that some executables are not here. The patch induced by `-D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS`, or done manually, is to delete the flag when `access` is called, thus checking for existence instead just like other Windows versions.

---

**EDIT:**

The patching is actually needed for every GCC program that invokes other executables, and not only `gcc.exe`. So far there is only `gcc.exe` and `collect2.exe`.

Here are the patching instruction :

1. Backup your `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe`.
2. Download and install *CFF Explorer* (direct link [here](http://www.ntcore.com/files/ExplorerSuite.exe)).
3. Open `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` with CFF Explorer.
4. On the left panel, click on *Import Directory*.
5. In the module list that appears, click on the *msvcrt.dll* line.
6. In the import list that appears, find `_access`. Be careful here, the list is long, and there are multiple `_access` entries. The last one (the very last entry for me) is probably the good one.
7. When you click on the `_access` line, an address should appear on the list header, in the 2nd column 2nd row, just below *FTs(IAT)*. Write down that address on notepad (for me, it is 00180948, it may be different). I will refer to this address as F.
8. On the left panel, click on *Address Converter*.
9. Three fields should appear, enter address F in the *File Offset* field.
10. Write down on notepad a 6 bytes value : the first two bytes are FF 25, the last 4 are the address that appeared in the VA field, IN REVERSE. For example, if 00586548 appeared in the VA field, write down FF 25 48 65 58 00 (spaces added for legibility). I will refer to this value as J. This value J is the instruction that jumps to the `_access` function.
11. On the left panel, click on *Section Headers*.
12. In the section list that appeared on the right, click on the *.text* line (the .text section is where the code resides).
13. In the editor panel that appeared below, click on the magnifier and, in the *Hex* search bar, search for a series of 11 `90` (`9090909090...`, 90 is NOP in assembly). This is to find a code cave (unused space) to insert the patch, which is 11 bytes long. Once you found a code cave, write down the offset of the first 90. The exact offset is displayed on the very bottom as *Pos : xxxxxxxx*. I will refer to this offset as C.
14. Use the editor to change the sequence of 11 `90` : the first 5 bytes are 80 64 E4 08 06. These 5 bytes are the instruction that prevents the wrong behavior. The last 6 bytes are the value J (edit the next 6 bytes to J, ex. FF 25 48 65 58 00), to jump back to the `_access` function.
15. Click on the arrow icon (*Go To Offset*) a bit below, and enter 0, to navigate to the beginning of the file.
16. Use the Hex search bar again to search for value J. If you find the bytes you just modified, skip. The J value you need is located around many value containing FF 25 and 90 90. That is the DLL jump table. Write down the offset of the value J you found (offset of the first byte, FF). I will refer to this offset as S. Note 1: If you can't find the value, maybe you picked the wrong `_access` in step 6, or did something wrong between step 6 to 10. Note 2: The search bar doesn't loop when it hit the end; go to offset 0 manually to re-find.
17. Use a hexadecimal 32-bit 2-complement calculator (like this one : [calc.penjee.com](http://calc.penjee.com/?s=r)) to calculate C - S - 5. If your offset C is 8C0 and your offset S is 6D810, you must obtain FF F9 30 AB (8C0 minus 6D810, minus 5).
18. Replace the value J you found in the file (at step 16) by 5 bytes : the first byte is E9, the last 4 are the result of the last operation, IN REVERSE. If you obtained FF F9 30 AB, you must replace the value J (ex: FF 25 48 65 58 00) by E9 AB 30 F9 FF. The 6th byte of J can be left untouched. These 5 bytes are the jump to the patch.
19. File -> Save

Notes : You should have modified a total of 16 bytes. If the patched program crash, you did something wrong. Even if it doesn't work, this patch can't induce a crash.

Let me know if you have difficulties somewhere.

Comment: I would really like to try 3rd myself incase i run into such problem again. Does 2nd mean adding that line when compiling e.g. arm...gcc led.c -D... Because using that i still got the message. As i am now, i sadly have to use Vista, no escape from this(I hate it too).

Comment: @s3v3ns I added the instructions. About the 2nd solution, unfortunately it means downloading all the eabi gcc source and recompile it.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by the 18th. Where should i put the value? The place with a lot of FF 25 and 90 90?

Comment: @s3v3ns Yes. The place with lots of FF 25 is the DLL jump table, and one of these entry should exactly correspond to J (ex: FF 25 48 65 58 00). This is where the program go to execute `access`. Here you replace these 6 bytes (the normal jump) by a jump to the patch (E9 ...).

Comment: Well, i am not getting that previous error anymore, which is very nice since now i have a new error to work with :D
***arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: redlib.specs: No such file or directory***
I get that when using LPCxpresso. I get another when i just try via CMD(arm-...-gcc led.c) ***C:\Users\iamuser\Documents\LPCXpresso_7.6.2_326\workspace\led>arm-none-eabi-gcc -led.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin-0.dll not found
compilation terminated.***
That .dll is there, i checked.
But i guess that is another topic?

Comment: @s3v3ns Could you provide a new dump `arm-none-eabi-gcc -v led.c 2>dump.txt` ?

Comment: @s3v3ns Also, can you upload the .exe you patched ? It looks like you did it right, but there is a small chance you missed a bit at some point.

Comment: It is weird because it shows the create process error in the log but not in the cmd http://justpaste.it/jioj
And the file http://www.upload.ee/files/4531393/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe.html

Comment: @s3v3ns That's probably good news, but the patch you did is ALMOST good. The patch in the code cave is good, but somehow you calculated the subtraction wrong. Your patch is at offset 555, and the jump table entry is at offset 73C70. The calculation should be 555 - 73C70 - 5 = FFF8C8E0, but somehow you did 0 - 73C70 - 5 = FFF8C38B. Thus the jump is wrong, this should have made the exe crash, but by extreme (bad) luck, it jumps to something with valid (but wrong) behavior. To correct this, you just have to search for E98BC3F8FF, and replace it by E9 E0 C8 F8 FF.

Comment: Ah this is embarrassing, i am 100% i remember doing C(555)-S-5. I have no idea how this happened and i didn't bother to do it twice.

Comment: Now i just have cannot find 'ld'. At least this is not as intimidating as previous ones.
https://justpaste.it/saved/8602305/424182bc
People seem to recommend reinstalling. Ill try and reinstall everything and apply the patched .exe

Comment: @s3v3ns It seems collect2.exe need a patch too. Just follow the exact same procedure for collect2.exe. Be careful, CFF explorer doesn't close the previous file if you open another. Close CFF before to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I am sadly out of time and have to wait until next week to try. Just a heads up, will i end up updating a lot of different files :D? But anyways, you have saved me from an error that bugged me for a long time and did not let me get any work done. I would give you all my fingers, but unfortunately i can only give you my thumb. Thank you. This guide will help vista users a lot (Screw vista!)

Comment: @s3v3ns You will have to patch all the GCC programs that need to execute other files. I don't think there are this many. Hopefully `collect2.exe` is the last. `as.exe` will probably be invoked if you add assembly to your program. I don't which program invokes `as.exe`, but you will probably have to patch it too if isn't `gcc.exe`. I added a more detailed explanation of the problem in my answer.

Comment: The guide was excellent, now that i read the 18th, it makes sense, i was just trying to be safe then and that calculation i have no idea, how that went wrong.

Comment: @s3v3ns Probably just a misstep when using the calculator. Next time take a look at the recap line on the online calculator. Let me know if you could get everything working.

Comment: so i started trying to edit the collect2.exe, but i am stuck on step 16. I can not find the J value in the 25, 90 90 area, only the one i wrote earlier. I double checked and don't think I did anything wrong.

Comment: @s3v3ns Can you upload your collect2.exe ? Original or edited, but tell me which is it.

Comment: @s3v3ns So, the import directory entry is the very last. When you click on it, it gives you 00 14 7F 48 in the 2nd header row. In the address converter, you obtain 00 54 C5 48, which gives a jump instruction J of FF 25 48 C5 54 00. Then you can find this value at offset 62688 (of .text section). If you have further problems after this, just mention the offset of your code cave.

Comment: I did one stupid mistake, it seems to work now, which is freaking awesome. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @s3v3ns No more problems ? You can actually compile now ?

Comment: Yea, i can build now, only some weird warning, but other than that i am good