# Qt with MinGW: g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, g++, mingw

I have a project originally build with Qt 4.8.6 for Embedded linux + ARM. This project is a user interface which has already been coded to be compiled as a Windows Desktop app and years ago I successfully did so. Now I have to recompile it once again for Windows, but I keep getting this error

> g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

when getting to the point of compiling main.cpp.

Solutions found on the web didn't help. Steps done:

- I was originally trying to compile it with Qt 5.7. Thinking it could be library incompatibility, I installed Qt 4.8.6 with correspondent MinGW version. [EDIT] I tested the installation with a Hello World program achieving 100% success
- Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory), I added the paths of both the new Qt and MinGW to PATH, no success. Notice that I'm able to perfectly compile and run other projects with Qt 5.7 and it is not linked in PATH.
- Following [this link](https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/1164187-erro-compiladores-de-c-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory/), I went to conclude I had several libraries linked to the project which were not compiled yet. I managed to successfully compile all of them and double checked the inclusion paths in my .pro file. This was clearly a problem to be solved, but it didn't help with the issue in question.
- I checked for any new libraries that could be incompatible with Windows; found one and put its header inclusion inside a define. No results.

So now I'm without ideas. Unfortunately I don't remember getting this error when I compiled the app for Windows years ago, so I don't even have a clue on what is happening. Here is the message I get in Compile Output:

[image: Compilation output with error message]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the command that you use to build ? Did you restart after adding the paths ? Is there a makefile that you use ? I had a similar issue once and it was just because of a simple typo error in the makefile.

Comment: You probably need to rerun qmake.

Comment: @VishaalShankar I build it inside Qt Creator: `clean all`, `run qmake`, `rebuild all`. I restarted after adding the paths. I use the Makefile generated by the execution of the just mentioned steps inside QtCreator.

Comment: @drescherjm I did that after every mentioned step above, no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution to the problem.

The .pro file had a define `DEFINES += COMPILE_DATE=\\\"$$DATE\\\"` which was calling the define `DATE =$$system($${PWD}/../../get_compile_date.bat)`. The .bat file this define was pointed out is somehow incompatible with Windows. Its contents is `date | tr -d " "`. Once the call to this file was commented, the problem stop occuring.