# Eclipse C++ Setup

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to switch from Dev-C++ to Eclipse (Version 12/18, 4.10.0) , but I am not able to Compile in Eclipse. I installed MinGW, edited the Pathvariable, restared the PC, installed the C++ Eclipse IDE, created a new Project there I choosed MinGW as my Compiler, and wrote a Hello World.

The Code is:

```
#include<iosteam>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

The Error Message I get is the following:

> error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

What do I need to do to be able to build/run Proramms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory?

Comment: Yes I have but none of the soulutions worked for me.

Comment: There is a typo in your include file name which also leads to the error message "No such file or directory". If you change it to "iostream", does that change anything?

Comment: The typo is just here, because I thought I do not need to copy & paste it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything you need to be able to build/run programs. Maybe something is flawed in the configuration. You should separate the tasks to find out the problem.

First try to compile your minimal example by executing g++ from a console like that:
`g++ main.cpp`. If you get the same error message then you have to fix your Mingw-w64 setup.

If this works, then something is wrong with eclipse. You might want to check different project types. When using `Makefile` projects, you perhaps have more possibilities to do checks on the console.