# Can't run VSCode properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, g++

I am a beginner at using VSCode and wanted to code a bit with C++&C. I discovered that I had to add on some extensions and add a compiler to make things work, so I followed this video: https://youtu.be/0HD0pqVtsmw.
I followed it and everything was fine but even then when I started coding I still had bugs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDEqj.png. I kept searching youtube and I couldnt get any help, I tried to re-install and everything went smoothly too but this problem occured, https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ5gW.png. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CreateProcess: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.