# c programming error: no such file or directory

Tags: c, windows

I'm very new to c programming and I'm trying to run a basic Hello World program and get this message:

C:\c-programming\elec1201\c1>gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

The path is correct. I get this message both in the command prompt and Windows PowerShell. I ran a -save-temps program to see where the compilation terminates, and it ends after creating a hello.s file. Also, when I intentionally make errors in the code the compiler reports them. How to fix this?

Comment: Is gcc in your path? I assume your hello.c is located in the c1 directory where you are located. To be clear; you need to either have gcc directly in the c1 directory or in the windows path (Advanced system settings --> Environment Variables --> PATH) to be able to run this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CreateProcess: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory)